# How to close select on mouse out of select?

Tags: angular

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 no-right-border">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFirstName">Filter:</label>
                    <select class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterObject" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="setSelectedFilter($event)">
                        <option *ngFor="let searchFilter of searchData.searchFilters" [ngValue]="searchFilter">{{searchFilter.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this select box. It opens when i click on select, but what i want is to close when i hover out of select ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default closed/opened tag for select so it won't be easy. Better approach is to create a ul-li list (make it looks like select box) and to do something like:

```
conditionForTheListToBeShown: boolean = false;

<span (click)="setConditionValue(true)">Expand the list</span>
<ul *ngIf="conditionForTheListToBeShown" (mouseleave)="setConditionValue(false)">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i know that i can use ul li but i need to do it with select because i already have a logic  on backed for that